# How to change the slide out speed of a boostrap modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a custom animation (see http://hawkee.com/snippet/16154/) for the modal dialogs in my site.

Here's my CSS code:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The problem is, the modal slides out too quickly and the animation isn't very smooth. I'd prefer a smooth animation for the disappearing dialog if possible. Is this something I'd need to use JQuery for?

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you would want to change is `transition: all 1.5s;`.

You would want to make the `1.5s` slower, to your desired speed. You can write this in seconds with `5s` making the animation 5 seconds long, or writing it in milliseconds with `5000ms` making it 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds long.

To solve the 'jerkiness' of your animation, add `ease` to the end of that command, to make the animation accelerate in speed at the beginning and decelerate at the end.

So if you wanted your animation to be 3 seconds in length with easing, you would write:

```
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
```

Comment: This only changes the animation for the modal *appearing*, which is not what I'm having an issue with. The issue is with it disappearing. It does the animation (apparently faster than normal), in a choppy manner, and then disappears.